# Check if sub string in cell match with other string from range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a range of cells with these string values:

```
A1: text1
A2: text2
A3: text3
```

And a column with these other string values:

```
B1: text1 text2 sampletext  
B2: text2 text3 sampletext    
B3: text3 sampletext    
B4: text1 sampletext    
B5: text1 sampletext
```

I have to check if the text in column A is a sub string of the text in column B.
If yes, set in column C the text from column A.

Like this:

```
C1: text1 text2
C2: text2 text3
C3: text3
C4: text1
C5: text1
```

Comment: While correcting your question I wonder if there is a mistake in your example: Where is `C5: text1` in your output?

Comment: yes I think that was not copied.. i'll correct it.. but i wnat C5 also

Answer (score 0):

Try the following small macro:

```
Sub BuildList()
    Dim N As Long, M As Long
    Dim i As Long, s1 As String, s2 As String

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    M = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim wordlist(1 To N) As String

    For i = 1 To N
        wordlist(i) = Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To M
        ary = Split(Cells(i, "B"), " ")
        For j = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            For k = 1 To N
                If wordlist(k) = ary(j) Then
                    Cells(i, "C") = Cells(i, "C") & " " & wordlist(k)
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```